# Добавление данных

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Почему в Management Studio это запрос проходит, а в Visual Studio 2017 нет? В чем ошибка?

```
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE FROM bus;
    INSERT INTO bus(ID_bus, board_number, regist_number, number_of_places, mark) VALUES (1, '708', 'А708КА55', '50', 'Hyundai');
    INSERT INTO bus(ID_bus, board_number, regist_number, number_of_places, mark) VALUES (2, '708', 'А708КА55', '27', 'Hyundai');
    INSERT INTO bus(ID_bus, board_number, regist_number, number_of_places, mark) VALUES (3, '415', 'Р415ОГ55', '90', 'Газель');
    INSERT INTO bus(ID_bus, board_number, regist_number, number_of_places, mark) VALUES (4, '257', 'Р257АА55', '11', 'Mercedes');
    INSERT INTO bus(ID_bus, board_number, regist_number, number_of_places, mark) VALUES (5, '107', 'Г107АЗ55', '19', 'Ikarus');
    INSERT INTO bus(ID_bus, board_number, regist_number, number_of_places, mark) VALUES (6, '987', 'А987НН55', '55', 'ПАЗ');
    INSERT INTO bus(ID_bus, board_number, regist_number, number_of_places, mark) VALUES (7, '951', 'К951ГТ55', '40', 'ПАЗ');
    INSERT INTO bus(ID_bus, board_number, regist_number, number_of_places, mark) VALUES (8, '411', 'Л411ЛГ55', '20', 'Camena');
    INSERT INTO bus(ID_bus, board_number, regist_number, number_of_places, mark) VALUES (9, '256', 'О256РА55', '10', 'Mercedes');
    INSERT INTO bus(ID_bus, board_number, regist_number, number_of_places, mark) VALUES (10, '147', 'О147АЕ55', '100', 'Isuzu');
GO
```

Жалуется на SET, пишет

```
SQL71006 :: Разрешена только одна инструкция на пакет. Между инструкциями может потребоваться разделитель пакетов, например "GO".
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698481/error-in-sql-script-only-one-statement-is-allowed-per-batch

Comment: поменял свойство действие при сборке = нет, проблема не решилась

Comment: попробуйте добавить GO между всеми строками. Так же можно собрать все insert в один. `insert into bus(...) values(...первый набор значений...), (...второй набор значений...), ...`